# Aurelia - How to access class attributes from jquery functions?

Tags: aurelia

I'm having some problems to deal with Aurelia together with jquery.

I'm trying to access the "model" in my class, from the jCrop function (which is a jquery), but I'm getting the message "model is not defined".

ModalCrop.js

```
export class ModalCrop{
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) image = '';

  model = {
        ImageURL: this.imageBase64,
        PositionX: 0,
        PositionY: 0,
        Width: 0,
        Height: 0
    };

  imageChanged(newValue, oldValue){
        var imageCrop = $(this.thepicture);
        imageCrop.jWindowCrop({
            targetWidth:500,
            targetHeight:500,
            onChange: function(result) {
                this.model.Width = result.cropW;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

HTML Component

```
<div class="modal-image-content">
     <img ref="thepicture" src="${image}">
</div>
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Felipe, I noticed that you've asked several questions (I've answered two of them) but you haven't accepted the answers on any of them.  When you receive a satisfactory answer, you should click the check mark to the left of the answer that you found most helpful.  This helps StackOverflow.com work well.  It also helps individual users earn points for successful answers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a problem of scope.  To fix it, change the `onChange` function call to use a thick arrow function, like this:

```
onChange: (result) => {
            this.model.Width = result.cropW;
        }
```

If that doesn't work, simply add `var self = this;` as the first line in your `imageChanged` function and then change `this.model.Width` to `self.model.Width`.